# Split JS string regex upper followed by lowercase

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ecmascript-2018

I have a long javascript variable articles that I am trying to split where a lowercase character is immediately followed by an uppercase

Using regex I have tried:

```
var article2 = article2.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/);
```

but only managed to split on every word

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and expected output?

Comment: If lowercase *is followed* by uppercase, you need `.split(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/)`, but it will only work in Chrome and Node.JS that are ECMAScript 2018 compliant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thank you that worked perfectly. You should post an answer and I'll mark it as chosen. Until then I'll fill it in. Thank you

Comment: Ok, let me post then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your JS environment is ECMAScript 2018 compliant (see [what regex features it supports](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/javascript-whats-new-in-ecmascript-2018-es2018-17ede97f36d5#ca4f)), you may use [**lookbehinds**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
.split(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/)
```

A `(?<=[a-z])` pattern is a lookbehind that requires a digit immediately to the left of the current location and `(?=[A-Z])` is a positive lookahead that requires a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IlqUGN/1).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var article2 = "SplitJavaScriptString";

// you are doing this (include Small case & Upper case)
console.log(article2.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/)); 

// is this what you want (exclude Small case & Upper case)
console.log(article2.split(/[A-Z][a-z]/).filter(e => e != ''));
```